# 85 Hz on old/new driver looks the same like 75 Hz on previous one?

Tags: linux, drivers, display

I have old philips 107T5 [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube) and [Nvidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia) graphics card. I used old Nvidia driver (but it wasn't 'legacy' one when I installed it) for few years but recently I decided to install other Linux distribution. I used 75 Hz refresh rate and 1024x768 resolution on my previous distribution.

After I installed the new distribution I had to install a Nvidia driver so I downloaded one from the Nvidia site (this time only legacy supported my card so I downloaded legacy and installed it). It wasn't automatically updating `xorg.conf` but I had my previous `xorg.conf` copy and I used it. When I run [X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) I could only choose 85 and 75 Hz, 85 was checked as default.

And now what shocks me: that default 85 Hz looks identically like 75 Hz on previous driver looked (at least to me). I tried 75 Hz out of curiosity and it's too bright, hurts, etc. But on the previous driver 75 Hz wasn't hurting my eyes. Why is it different? It's the same number after all, so it should always give the same results, right? That's my first question.

Second question: Is 85 Hz OK for that monitor model? Would it break it? I tried to find the optimal refresh rate for this model but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a specification sheet for [107T56 (Stealth Black) and 107T51 (Mist White)](http://www.p4c.philips.com/files/1/107t56_74/107t56_74_pss_aen.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: Thanks. But i have to say... i don't understand. 70Hz at 1024x768?? Or how do i read it?

Comment: these are factory preset modes, you can use 85 Hz, the monitor supports vertical scanning frquencies from 50 to 160 Hz.